# How to render subchild above parent overlay

Tags: css

I want a gray overlay above all children except for the `selected` one. Given the following structure:

```
<div class="parent">

  <!-- I have this subparent which is absolute. I cannot remove it... -->
  <div class="subParent1">
    <div class="subParent2">

      <!-- This child I want to be above the OVERLAY, aka not greyed out -->
      <div class="child selected">child</div>

      <div class="child">child</div>
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <!--   This component is underneat subParent in the tree structure -->    
  <div class="grayOverlay"></div>
  
</div>
```

[Here's an exact fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyfb3e2h/2/). Maybe, I could use a pseudo-element instead?

PS: I updated the children to be a bit more nested to align with my actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the reference from below code. I have altered the CSS a bit. I have added `z-index` wherever required you can optimise that. Also, removed `position: absolute;` from `subParent1` and added `top: 0; left: 0;` on the `grayOverlay`. You can optimise it or change it as per you preference.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.grayOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(107 114 128 / 0.8);
  z-index: 11000;
}

.subParent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 12000;
}

.child {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.childIWantOverOverlay {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 12000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="subParent1">
    <div class="child childIWantOverOverlay">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
  </div>

  <!--   This component is underneat subParent in the tree structure -->
  <div class="grayOverlay"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly on the fiddle, but I cannot translate it at all onto my actual example. Would you be open to hopping on a 10m call so that you can check it out? -thanks

Comment: For the time being, I think I found the issue. My children are a bit more nested in my actual code. Unfortunately, I cannot remove that nesting. Would it be still possible? (I have updated the example fiddle!)

Comment: That's great. Try to dig more, you will find the exact troublemaker. In meantime, you can also post your code here or any link and post that link here. Surely will try to help to resolve your issue. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, yes, I've updated the jsfiddle in the question to align more with my actual issue! I'm posting it here for convenience: https://jsfiddle.net/xyfb3e2h/2/ . Hopefully, that has a solution as well...

Comment: You can lower the overlay's z-index to 9 and add some transparency to your child divs like this --> https://prnt.sc/eZCfUOO8BmKm to trick the viewer. I have updated your fiddle as well.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find the updated fiddle :/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/fO0X6r3gtjwh
https://prnt.sc/eZCfUOO8BmKm
You can see the above URLs for the changes in CSS. The updated page will look like this ---> https://prnt.sc/tboSzCBylQOm

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yeah this might work. WIll give it a try. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**

Perhaps also consider use a pseudo-element for this, if it is acceptable in the actual use case.

This approach is more isolated, so it might be less likely to have conflict with other existing elements in the actual project.

Example with pseudo-element:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.child");

let i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  divs[i].classList.toggle("selected");
  if (i < 2) {
    divs[i + 1].classList.toggle("selected")
    i++;
    return;
  };
  if (i >= 2) {
    i = 0;
    divs[i].classList.toggle("selected");
  }

});
```

```css
/* Can Change */

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}


/*   Add this */

.parent::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgb(107 114 128 / 0.5);
  z-index: 50;
}


/*   Disabled for now
.grayOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(107 114 128 / 0.5);
  z-index: 50;
}
*/


/* CANNOT CHANGE */

.subParent1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Can Change */

.child {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 25;
  position: relative;
}


/* Can Change */

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  /*   Add z-index */
  z-index: 100;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="subParent1">
    <div class="subParent2">
      <div class="child selected">child</div>
      <div class="child">child</div>
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--   This component is underneat subParent in the tree structure. I cannot move this into subParent1 -->
  <!--  <div class="grayOverlay"></div> -->

</div>
```

**Update:** also added `position: relative` on `child`.

It seems that this can be achieved by removing the `z-index` on `grayOverlay` and `subParent1` (the `grayOverlay` is still stacked on top due to natural placement), and add some `z-index` on `selected`.

Example:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.child");

let i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  divs[i].classList.toggle("selected");
  if (i < 2) {
    divs[i + 1].classList.toggle("selected")
    i++;
    return;
  };
  if (i >= 2) {
    i = 0;
    divs[i].classList.toggle("selected");
  }

});
```

```css
/* Can Change */

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Can Change */

.grayOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(107 114 128 / 0.5);
  /* Removed z-index */
}


/* CANNOT CHANGE */

.subParent1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  /* Removed z-index */
}


/* Can Change */

.child {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
  /*   Add position */
  position: relative;
}


/* Can Change */

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  /*   Add z-index */
  z-index: 100;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="subParent1">
    <div class="subParent2">
      <div class="child selected">child</div>
      <div class="child">child</div>
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--   This component is underneat subParent in the tree structure. I cannot move this into subParent1 -->    
  <div class="grayOverlay"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this works perfectly on the fiddle, but I cannot translate it at all onto my actual example. Would you be open to hopping on a 10m call just so you can check it out? -thanks

Comment: For the time being, I've updated the jsfiddle to align more with my actual code. My children are a bit more nested. Would it still be possible?

Comment: @Martin It seems that the updated fiddle nested 2 `subParent`, I've updated the answer to cover this. Not sure if this will work in the actual project, but hopefully it could still help as a reference.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to translate well into the actual code :( would you have 10m to go through it over a quick google meet?